# How are pixels arranged in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have 2x2 image

Shouldn't the pixels be arranged like this?

```
1 2 // each number is a pixel
3 4
```

I'm having trouble accessing a pixel with x and y because 
when x = 1 and y = 0  i get index 2 but prints the rgb values of pixel 4

so it's something like?

```
1 2 // each number is a pixel
4 3
```

Here's the code that I use

```
index = y + x * s->w;
c = s->format->palette->colors[index]; // c is an SDL_Color and s is an SDL_Surface*
```

I also use this for loop and still prints the same

```
for (Uint8 i = *(Uint8 *)s->pixels; i < s->w*s->h; i++) {
    c = s->format->palette->colors[i];
    printf("%u %u %u %u \n", i, c.r , c.g , c.b);
}
```

SDL_Surface struct definition from the SDL documentation

```
typedef struct SDL_Surface {
    Uint32 flags;                           /* Read-only */
    SDL_PixelFormat *format;                /* Read-only */
    int w, h;                               /* Read-only */
    Uint16 pitch;                           /* Read-only */
    void *pixels;                           /* Read-write */

    /* clipping information */
    SDL_Rect clip_rect;                     /* Read-only */

    /* Reference count -- used when freeing surface */
    int refcount;                           /* Read-mostly */

/* This structure also contains private fields not shown here */
} SDL_Surface;
```

Comment: I've edited the code

Comment: You should use `pixels` to access pixels, `colors` looks like a color table.

Comment: The documentation said, " So, to determine the color of a pixel in a 8-bit surface: we read the color index from surface->pixels and we use that index to read the SDL_Color structure from surface->format->palette->colors. "

Comment: Your quote is the answer. You should get the index from `->pixels`, not compute it.

Comment: 'for (Uint8 i = *(Uint8 *)s->pixels; i < s->w * s->h; i++) {
  c = s->format->palette->colors[i];
  printf("%u %u %u %u \n", i, c.r , c.g , c.b);
}' prints the same

Comment: When posting a comment, enclose your code in backticks: ` , otherwise formatting breaks.

Comment: There are still problems with the code. 1. You can't count on rows being tightly packed and should use `->pitch`. 2. `Uint8 i = *(Uint8 *)s->pixels; i < s->w * s->h;` makes no sense. You should probably use two nested loops for `y` and `x`, and access `->pixels` with something like `pixels[pitch * y + x]`, *but* it will only work for 1-byte-per-pixel formats with palette, so you should check that first.

Comment: Isn't `s->pitch` same as `s->w*s->h`?

Comment: Not necessarily. Also, you should white @username at the beginning of your messages when replying to someone (not under their question/answer), otherwise they might not get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uint8 *pixel = (Uint8 *)s->pixels,*index;
index = &pixel[y + x * s->pitch];
c = s->format->palette->colors[*index];
```

Got it doing using @holyblackcat's suggestion.